# Blank Screen on Boot in Dell Vostro 3750

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, dell, screen, dell-vostro

I have been using Ubuntu in My Acer Aspire 5920 and Aspire 1 since last many years.

Recently I purchased `Dell Vostro 3750` - Intel® Core™ i7-2670QM with Nvidia® Geforce™ GT 525M, 1GB (Quad Core)

I tried installing Ubuntu `11.10` and `12.04 beta`. I an able to use both from live CD without any problem. But when I install it, only a blank screen appears after the boot menu. I tried changing `quiet splast` to `nomodeset` and no splast. Didn't work. I am totally stuck here.

Comment: You're unlucky that you've bought a laptop with Optimus technology. Installing the nvidia drivers breaks as you've noticed. Boot into recovery mode and uninstall `nvidia-current`.